# how to argparse have argument print a string and do nothing else

Tags: python

I want to have an argument `--foobar` using Python `argparse`, so that whenever this argument appears, the program prints a particular string and exits.  I don't want to consume any other arguments, I don't want to check other arguments, nothing.

I have to call `add_argument` somehow, and then perhaps, from `parse_args()` get some information and based on that, print my string.

But even though I successfully used `argparse` before, I am surprised to find I have trouble with this one.

For example, none of the `nargs` values seem to do what I want, and none of the `action` values seem to fit.  They mess up with the other arguments, which I want to ignore once this one is seen.

How to do it?

Comment: It might be easier just to look in `sys.argv` before calling `parse_args`

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom `action=` parameter:

```
import argparse

class FoobarAction(argparse.Action):
  def __init__(self, option_strings, dest, **kw):
    self.message = kw.pop('message', 'Goodbye!')
    argparse.Action.__init__(self, option_strings, dest, **kw)
    self.nargs = 0
  def __call__(self, parser, *args, **kw):
    print self.message
    parser.exit()

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('--ip', nargs=1, help='IP Address')
p.add_argument('--foobar',
               action=FoobarAction,
               help='Abort!')
p.add_argument('--version',
               action=FoobarAction,
               help='print the version number and exit!',
               message='1.2.3')

args = p.parse_args()
print args
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#action-classes

#### EDIT:

It looks like there is already an `action=` that does exactly what `FoobarAction` does. `action='version'` is the way to go:

```
import argparse

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('--foobar',
               action='version',
               version='Goodbye!',
               help='Abort!')
args = p.parse_args()
print args
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to post this here, if it helps then great!

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='')
parser.add_argument('-foobar', '--foobar', help='Description for foobar argument',
                required=False)
args = vars(parser.parse_args())

if args['foobar'] == 'yes':
    foobar()
```

Usage:

```
python myscrip.py -foobar yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `action='store_true'` ([see the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#action)).

**arg_test.py:**

```
import argparse
import sys

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('--foobar', action='store_true')
args = p.parse_args()

if args.foobar:
    print "foobar"
    sys.exit()
```

**Usage:**

```
python arg_test.py --foobar
```

**Result:**

```
foobar
```